# requirejs returns a module with attach and notNeeded methods

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

The main question here is, in what cases does calling require(arrayOfPaths, onSuccess, onError) cause the onSuccess callback be called with an object, that instead of the module, return an object that has two methods: attach and notNeeded?
The secondary question is, what do these attach() and notNeeded() methods do?

I cannot find any documentation on these.

Reproduction of this scenario is pretty straightforward. I have an AMD module (TypeScript'ed) on some web server that I load using the require method. This call works the first time and works for multiple require calls for multiple, other AMD modules. However, if I refresh the page, which, with my logic causes the require calls to be made again, it no longer returns my AMD module but instead the object that I described above.

My assumption is that the object returned is a cached version of the object that maybe if I call attach() it will give me that cached object back. I haven't tested that though.

Here are a couple of things that throws the "caching" idea out of the window:
1. This is a browser Refresh (not Ctrl+R style) but still a refresh which means the page is loaded and any script tags added by requirejs should be gone
2. The path that I'm supplying to the require call has a ?ts= where  = new Date().getTime()

So, the path and call on the first call may be:

```
require(["http://someurl/provider.js?ts=123"], onSuccess, onError);
```

and on the second call, it may be:

```
require(["http://someurl/provider.js?ts=124"], onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: You "cannot find any documentation on these" because that's not a RequireJS thing. Please produce an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want the issue resolved.

Comment: I'll try to create an mcve but it will take some time. I can just jsfiddle something like this.
How are you so sure it's not a RequireJS thing? The behavior/artifact that I've described is *directly* from the require call. Can you elaborate on your conclusion that it's not a RequireJS thing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I created a a small web project that attempted to do the same thing I was doing and was not able to reproduce it. I don't think it's worthwhile for me to post the code that does not reproduce it, but I can if needed be.

But I did manage to make the behavior go away. First, a little background on my web project: my web project is an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app that uses the Angle theme from WrapBootstrap. If you're not familiar with this theme, it's basically bringing a bunch of third party libraries together such as angular, bootstrap, fontawesome, whirl, just to name a few.
Now, secondly, I searched my entire source code root folder and sub folders for the word 'notNeeded' and found that fastclick references it, but not necessarily create any objects with a notNeeded property. fastclick is one of the libraries that the Angle theme pulls in by default. fastclick was the only one that had any references to notNeeded; and thus excluding requirejs.
Finally, I tried removing fastclick from the list of modules that the ui.router tries to resolve and by doing that, it removed this behavior. I don't want to say that this is the answer since I would like to know exactly what prompted this behavior/artifact. Did the browser (IE) do this? As I play around with this some more, maybe I can get something verifiable out there.